# Apache POI - Allow calculation with time strings

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel sheet which contains some time values. These values are Durations formatted to Strings. When I try to do a sum on those values I get a 0 as result since Excel can't do sums on Strings. When I hit the enter button in the formula bar it does become a time so I the sum works. How do I change the value of the cell from a String to a time value? I already have the date format set up as `[hh:mm]` with a `DateFormat`

I start with an amount of time converted into seconds which I convert into a `Duration`

```
Duration clockedDuration = Duration.ofSeconds(clockedSeconds)
```

Then I format the Duration to a String using `DurationFormatUtils`

```
DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(duration.toMillis(), "HH:mm", true)
```

Then I set the cell value to the String that was just made

```
c.setCellValue(clockedDuration)
```

I then set the `CellStyle` to one that has a `DataFormat` that's set up as `[hh]:mm`

Lastly I make a sum of all the values in that particular column (B in this instance)

```
c = r.createCell(i++)
c.setCellFormula("SUM(B2:B" + lastRow +")")
c.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA)
```

This is the sheet before I hit the enter button on the first value in the row (09:52)

[image]

This is the sheet after I've hit the enter button in the formula bar

[image]

Comment: you may want to show some code here. How do you "try do a sum on those values"? Using setCellFormula()?

Comment: I've added my code to the OP

Comment: Are you using the XSSF-Classes (XSSFCell, XSSFWorkbook, ...)? If not, try those :)

Comment: Yes, I'm using the SXSSF variant.

Comment: Try cell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);

Comment: No luck with that I'm afraid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by dividing the seconds by 86400 to get a decimal value and then use `[hh]:mm` as the data format.

```
c.setCellValue(clockedSeconds / 86400)  // 24(hours) * 60(minutes) * 60(seconds) = 86400
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch: you mentioned to actually use formulas, and if you are hitting enter on the sheet "the sum works". Applying formulas is a two-liner, in addition to set the "value", you also need to format the cell type as being a formula:

```
XSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(rowIndex);
XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cellIndex);
cell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
cell.setCellFormula("sum(start:end)");
```

Edit: You also will want to make sure to use the XSSF-Classes

Comment: I have it set as a formula cell. I'll edit some code into the OP.

Comment: I've tried that but no luck. With hitting enter I mean that when I hit enter in the formula bar on the time value the formula works. I'll edit screenshots into the OP to make it more clear.

Comment: I've added screenshots now.